# jquery ajax popup partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Edit:
I'm having an issue I can't figure it out.
I have Javascript Jquery function to pop up an action from my controller.

my action works well when I entered it manually in browser.
Also, in my browser when I debug, in the preview section I get the form successfully, it's just don't pop up

my HTML:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/StudentPopup.js"></script>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="StudentDelete" data-id="@item.ReferenceID">Delete</a> |
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="StudentEdit" data-id="@item.ReferenceID">Edit</a> |
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="StudentDetail" data-id="@item.ReferenceID">Details</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
     var StudentDetailUrl = '/Students/PopupDetailsStudent';
$(function () {
    $(".StudentDetail").click(function () {

        var $buttonClicked = $(this);
        var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
        var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: StudentDetailUrl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { "Id": id },
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                $('#myModal').modal(options);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
             //   debugger;
                //pop up detail student

            },
            error: function () {
                debugger;
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult PopupDetailsStudent(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null) {return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);}
        UseClass us = new UseClass();
        StudentViewModel SSVM = new  StudentViewModel();
        List<Student> SS = new List<Student>();
        //reading all rows
        string strtable = "select * from Students where IsCurrent=1 And ReferenceID=" + id;
        var db = new DatabaseContext(StaticValues.connectionstr);
        try
        {
            var studentlist = db.Database.SqlQuery<Student>(strtable).ToList();
            SSVM = SSVM.ConvertStudentToStudentViewModel(studentlist[studentlist.Count - 1]);
            SSVM.StudentVisitList = us.StudentVisitListStudentRef(SSVM.ReferenceID);

        }catch (Exception ex){ }
        if (SSVM == null)
        {return HttpNotFound();}
        return PartialView(SSVM);
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? (and probably not related but you have `bootstrap.js` twice and `jquery.js` after `bootstrap.js`). You also have `datatype: "json",` which would throw an error because your returning html and delete the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. Your method should also be returning a `PartialView`

Comment: (bootstrap) yes that's right I didn't see it. I'm getting:Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags. can you elaborate on the JSON part? because it seem to work with a duplicated function for other modal

Comment: I have no idea what your really trying to do. You ajax call has `url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,` but you have not shown that method, Just the `PopupDetails()` method which returns a view (not `json`)

Comment: I initialize the variable before the JS function: var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '/Students/PopupDetails'; this is the url that I would like to open.

Comment: Then change your ajax to `datatype: "html",` - that method returns a view, not json (and see the first comment)

Comment: Updated. still no change. any other suggestions? I'm about to loose my mind. same code with different name works on another model.

Comment: "Invalid regular expression flags"...so presumably somewhere you use regular expressions. Can you show that code? If that's in your browser console it should take you to the line of code which is generating the error.

Comment: sorry, I edited my question.  I already fixed this issue. now when I click my link my JS function work fine and get in to the success part, my c# function is launched,works good and return what I expect. the weird thing is like the browser doesn't get my c# function return.

Comment: Change the controller action to return a partial view rather than regular (full) view.  You'll basically return a string which has html in it and the jQuery will handle the rest.  Also, you are calling the modal twice.  This shouldn't cause any error or anything but you should only call the `.modal(...)` once to show it.

Comment: Changed to partial view(edited). still no feedback from my browser. even tried to play with the model show.